# Moving controls in flowlayoutpanel issue

Tags: c#, winforms

I have Pictureboxes and labels created in the same foreach loop at runtime and all these pictureboxes and labels located on flowlayoutpanel.

[image: Main form appearance]

How i created those controls is

```
 foreach (var item in nodes)
 {
    imgurl = GetPictureFromData(item);//this string takes pic of film from a website with a function
    filmname = GetFilmName(item);//this string takes film name from same website with a function
    rating = GetFilmRate (item);//this takes imdb rating with a function

    Label lb = new Label {AutoSize = true, Margin = new Padding(190,0,0,0) };

    PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();//Movie pics

    lb.Font = new Font(Label.DefaultFont, FontStyle.Bold);

    lb.Text = filmname+" "+ rating+"/10" ;

    pb.ImageLocation = imgurl;
    pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize ;

    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pb);

    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lb);

    lb.BringToFront();
    pb.BringToFront();

  }
```

all pictures and labels taken from the same webpage.What i want to do is move the all labels down next to the related picture.

[image: My Form's wanted appearance.]

Comment: Put each set in a `TableLayoutPanel` that has 1 row and 2 cols, and then put that TLP in the FLP.

Comment: You should think about creating a UserControl with a PictureBox and a Label.

Comment: I've done what you said.Pictureboxes added properly to first column but labels not added .They're invisible.

Comment: @DonBoitnott your suggestion worked for me..I added a tablelayoutoanel with 1 row 2 columns and add pictureboxes to first column and the labels to second.I changed anchor property of labels to none my form appearance is now like how i wanted to be..